# Crosstabs to show data for all days in a given month

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to write a report that shows the daily values in a month. A small snippet of how the report should look:

```
                  01-Apr   02-Apr  03-Apr      .  .                               30-Apr 
 Attended Arrivals   1          2      0       .  .                                  1           
 Failed Arrivals     9          0      0                                             1
 Unattended Arrivals 0          5      0       .  .                                  1
```

I have copied my query below, the problem with this is, there could be days in a month with no records , and if I use the Activity._Created as a Column Group in the cross tab , it skips days in between. Any suggestions on how i could improve the query?

> SELECT  Activity.id, ActivityType.code, Activity._created, IF( 
>   Activity.`stateId` = 686 , 'FAILED Arrivals' , IF(Activity.typeId =
>   11,'Attended Departures' , 'Unattended Arrivals'  )  )  AS 'type'
>
> FROM  Activity
>
> LEFT JOIN ActivityType ON ActivityType.id = Activity.typeId
>
> WHERE Activity.typeId = 11 OR Activity.typeId = 12  ORDER BY
>   Activity._created
>
> Thanks

Comment: Why not store the dates in rows, and make the current rows as coluns?

Comment: Do you mean creating another table with the dates?

Comment: Something more along these lines: (http://www.hastebin.com/cajemadaji)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but according to my report format I need to display the dates as columns. If there is no record for a day, it should automatically fill those days with 0. I think i would need to use cross joins, but I am not sure how that works. Any idea?

Comment: Then set the column having a DEFAULT 0.